# How to get the files from an Eclipse project?

Tags: rascal

The function

```
set[loc] visibleFiles(loc l)
```

from from util::FileSystem allows you to get the files from a directory.

However it does not work if the location is an Eclipse project.
Suppose we apply

```
visibleFiles(|project://HelloWorld/|);
```

then we get the Java exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /HelloWorld(internal error)    at $shell$(|main://$shell$|)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /HelloWorld
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.newResource(Workspace.java:2131)
```

So, how to get the files in an Eclipse project?

For completeness I give the sample project with only one Java file:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the project scheme I think rascal wants to know the path in which it should start. Try `|project://HelloWorld/src/|`.

In the end the `visibleFiles` function is a wrapper for the `.ls` field of source locations (in combination with other source location functions).

Answer (score 0):

Adding "/src" doesn't really help.

```
visibleFiles(|project://HelloWorld/src/|);
```

results in

```
set[loc]: {|project://HelloWorld/src/|}
```

This is actually what we can expect, since

```
 isDirectory(|project://HelloWorld/src/|);
```

reduceer to "false", and we have

```
@doc{
Synopsis: lists all files recursively ignored files and directories starting    with a dot.
}
set[loc] visibleFiles(loc l) {
  if (/^\./ := l.file) 
    return {};
  else if (isDirectory(l)) 
    return {*visibleFiles(f) | f <- l.ls};
  else 
    return {l};
}
```

So, it boils down to applying "ls";

```
|project://HelloWorld/|.ls
```

gives the error I reported earlier, whereas

```
|project://HelloWorld/src/|.ls
```

gives the message

```
IO("You can only access ls on an existing location.")
```

Comment: could you make a github issue with the full stack trace? this should work. (also please report which version of rascal you are running)

Comment: Potentially silly question, but is HelloWorld a new project without any files yet? Using `ls` on the `src` folder works for me, but if you've just created the project the src directory shows up in the project explorer but doesn't really exist (on disk) until you add a file to it.